# ls でクエスチョンマークが表示された場合の対処法を教えてください。

Tags: linux, debian

Debian GNU/Linux 9にてとあるディレクトリで「ls」するとパーミッションが「???」となります。

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 nobody nogroup 131072 Feb  6 15:24 ..
-????????? ? ?      ?            ?            ? esparse
-????????? ? ?      ?            ?            ? esvalidate
```

このファイルを削除しようとすると「No such file or directory」と表示されます。

```
rm: cannot remove 'esparse': No such file or directory
```

chmodでも同様です。

原因がわからないのでご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`とあるディレクトリ` に読み取り権限はあるものの実行権限が無いのが原因かと考えられます。

`chmod a+x そのディレクトリ` など（必要に応じて `sudo` を付けつつ）してみてください。

Comment: chmodしてもNo such file or directoryになっちゃいますね。。権限の問題ですらなさそうです。

Comment: そのディレクトリはネットワーク越しにマウントしたものだったりしますか？

Comment: また、現時点で存在するものですか？

Comment: AzureのApp Service Linuxを使っていてsshからtouchで作成したファイルになります。現時点で存在するものとはどういうことでしょうか？理解が出来ていなくて申し訳ありません

Answer (score 0):

私も似たようなことが発生しました。
ファイルを元に戻すことはできませんでしたが、削除はすることができたのでその対応内容を共有させていただきます。
環境はCentOS7です。

```
$ cd /var/backup/hoge/.git/objects
$ ls -l c7
ls: c7/84918c2ca3792f813cc97f824280f13dabbd4a にアクセスできません: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません
合計 0
l????????? ? ? ? ?                ? 84918c2ca3792f813cc97f824280f13dabbd4a
```

`rm`や`chmod`はできず、`vim`などで同名のファイルを作成すると「???」が消えてパーミッションが表示されますが、その状態でそのファイルを`rm`するとまた元の状態に戻ってしまいました。
また、ディレクトリごと`rm`しようとしても、このファイルの存在によって失敗していました。

そこで`lsof`コマンドで確認したところ、ファイルの置かれているディレクトリが使用中でした。
そのプロセスを`kill`した後で`rm`すると、削除に成功しました。

```
$ lsof | grep hoge
fish      2134               admin  cwd       DIR              253,0        28 17312608 /var/backup/hoge/.git/objects
fish      2134               admin    3r      DIR              253,0        28 17312608 /var/backup/hoge/.git/objects
fish      2134 5996          admin  cwd       DIR              253,0        28 17312608 /var/backup/hoge/.git/objects
fish      2134 5996          admin    3r      DIR              253,0        28 17312608 /var/backup/hoge/.git/objects
lsof      6001               admin  cwd       DIR              253,0        28 17312608 /var/backup/hoge/.git/objects
grep      6002               admin  cwd       DIR              253,0        28 17312608 /var/backup/hoge/.git/objects
lsof      6003               admin  cwd       DIR              253,0        28 17312608 /var/backup/hoge/.git/objects

$ kill 2134
$ rm -rf /var/backup/hoge
```

結局なぜ「???」になっていたのか、そしてどうしてこれで削除できるようになったのかは私は分かっておらず恐縮ですが、解決のための何らかの糸口になりましたら幸いです。